# Why does VS Code create a hyperlink when you type "postalcode:"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have noticed that every time I type `postalcode` or any variation followed by a colon ':', VS Code thinks it is a hyperlink.

You can try this yourself by opening VS Code, open a new file, enter `postalcode:` and see the hyperlink appear.

**VS Code**

```
Version: 1.37.1 (user setup)    
Commit: f06011ac164ae4dc8e753a3fe7f9549844d15e35    
Date: 2019-08-15T16:17:55.855Z    
Electron: 4.2.7
```

Anyone else see this happening?

Comment: Mine doesn't. If you launch it as `code --disable-extensions`, does the behaviour stop?

Comment: my VCS has no suggestion for anything `postal` or `postalcode`

Comment: Onoes vscode is going postal!!1!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, good idea. I tried this and it does appear to be an extension doing this. Now off to hunt down the extension... thanks.